# A non-conventional definition of topoi

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, topos-theory

In "[Toward a Galoisian interpretation of homotopy theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007157)" (2000), B. Toën wrote:

> Pour expliquer notre point de vue sur la notion de champs rappelons une construction (non conventionnelle) du topos de l’espace $X$ (i.e. d’une catégorie qui est naturellement équivalente à la catégorie des faisceaux sur X) qui n’utilise pas directement la notion de faisceaux. Pour cela, soit $Pr(X)$ la catégorie des préfaisceaux d’ensembles sur l’espace topologique $X$. Dans cette catégorie on considère l’ensemble $W$ des morphismes qui induisent des isomorphismes fibre à fibre, et on forme la catégorie $W^{−1}Pr(X)$, obtenue à partir de $Pr(X)$ en inversant formellement les
> morphismes de $W$. On peut alors vérifier que $W^{−1}Pr(X)$ est naturellement  ́equivalente à la catégorie des faisceaux sur $X$. Il faut remarquer que les objets de $W^{−1}Pr(X)$ sont les préfaisceaux sur $X$, mais ses ensembles de morphismes sont en réalité isomorphes aux ensembles de morphismes entre faisceaux associés. Aussi surprenant que cela puisse paraître, cette construction montre qu’il n’est pas nécessaire de connaître la notion de faisceaux pour pouvoir parler de la catégorie des faisceaux sur $X$.

I would like to know if this is the first apparition of this non-conventional definition of topos.

and

Can $X$ be a general site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This idea originates in homotopy theory and is due to Jardine, "Simplicial presheaves", JPAA **47** Issue 1 (1987) pp 35–87, https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(87)90100-9 ([pdf](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82485559.pdf)).

One can not take for $X$ any site, this definition only works in a topos with "enough points".

Comment: Well, appropriately formulated, it can be generalized. A presheaf morphism induces isomorphism on stalks if and only if it is carried to an isomorphism by the left adjoint of the inclusion of sheaves into presheaves. And any subtopos $S$ of any topos $P$ is equivalent to $W^{-1}P$, where $W$ is the class of those morphisms in $P$ which are carried to an isomorphism under the left adjoint of the inclusion from $S$ into $P$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, but the point of the quoted material seems be mainly that, in the case of a sheaf subtopos $S$ of a presheaf topos $P$ on a space, "the class of those morphisms in $P$ which are carried to an isomorphism under the left adjoint of the inclusion from $S$ into $P$" can be defined without knowing anything about $S$, namely as the morphisms that induce isomorphisms on all stalks.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Given any small site, one can define $W$ as the smallest class of maps between presheaves closed under finite limits as well as under colimits and containing inclusions of covering sieves. The localization of the category presheaves by $W$ is then (equivalent to) the category of sheaves.